# Ember data isDeleted marked records still remain in hasMany (embedded always)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We were trying to apply ember data to multiple levels of nested JSON.

```
Model A hasMany Model B
and Model B is embedded always in Model A
```

In this scenario if we are editing a record of A and delete all B. 
On calling `deleteRecord` on B, the records are marked isDeleted, but are still present as children of A.

Question 1:
Is this a good scenario, say if there are number of records B has and all of them are marked isDeleted. Also, if the user ends of adding more of B and deleting more. Won't deleteRecord, followed by createRecord multiple times, create a long list of records marked isDeleted. Is it good for design of App.

Question 2:
For embedded records, on delete of child records, commit is necessary to call to get of isDeleted marked child records ?